# Responsive images, scale down only

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I'm trying to work out how to make images responsive but scale down only, all solutions I have found so  far use `max-width:100%` or `max-width:??px` but these also stretch the image to its parent container and that's not the result I'm after.

I currently have a jquery fix:

```
 var ww = $(window).width(),
     iw = $('img').width();

 if(ww < iw) {
  $('img').css('width',ww - 20);
 }
```

but would like a css only solution.

So say I have an image with a 640px width if browser window is wider than 640px the image should remain 640px wide and not stretched to fit its parent container, but if the browser window is smaller then and only then should the image be responsive to fit inside the browser window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should do it with `max-width`, see the demo.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d5mLhdpp/

Comment: I'm sure I had tried this before but gave it another shot and it seems to work, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<style type="text/css">
img{width:640px;}

@media (max-width: 640px) 
{
    img{width:100%;}
}
</style>

<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
```

Comment: Trying not to do it with media queries as images may be different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...I'm refining my answer for you situation. First of all, you need to set some bounds first in the css like this:

```
img.specialClass {
  width: 100%;
}
```

And now here comes the tricky part. I'm using jQuery here for ease of use:

```
$('img.specialClass').each(function() {
  var $img = $(this);
  var fakeImg = new Image;
  fakeImg.src = $img.attr('src');
  fakeImg.onload = function() {
    var width = this.naturalWidth;
    $img.css('max-width', width);
  }
});
```

I would initially hide the image because the max-width is not being set until they are fully loaded. Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Images are different sizes so adding width:xx; will not work.

Comment: @AnnaRiekic since the images are dynamic widths, i.e. Different sizes, then each element would have to have an inline style max-width applied to them dynamically with JavaScript.

Comment: @AnnaRiekic there is not a pure CSS solution if you do not want to specify each image individually with a max width property. I have refined my solution above using CSS and jQuery.